# Can't start fail2ban on Nginx-Apache server

Tags: nginx

As my host and I are at an impasse, I thought I’d reach out for a bit of help. I’m trying to wrap my head around this stuff and not sure how to proceed.

I have a VPS account and host a few WP sites for clients. Server info: **Nginx** (1.17.0) – **Apache** (2.4.39) on **CentOS 7.6**.

After recently reading about the strengths of fail2ban I decided to give it a try (ie, f2b with the WP plugin). I asked the hosting company to install f2b and they did so a couple of days ago. Unfortunately, I’ve not been able to get it off the ground at all and they’re not willing to help unless I give them some coin.

They installed v **0.9.7**, although the current version appears to be **0.10.4**. Following instructions from the following guides and docs:
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-fail2ban-on-centos-7
- https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-fail2ban-on-centos/
- https://docs.wp-fail2ban.com/en/4.2/introduction.html

I installed the plugin, and performed the following:

1. confirmed that **/wp-content/plugins/wp-fail2ban/filters.d/** contained **wordpress-hard.conf, wordpress-soft.conf, and wordpress-extra.conf** (as listed in the docs)
2. `sudo systemctl enable fail2ban` = no error
3. I created the **jail.local** file and placed the following code inside:

```
    [DEFAULT]

    ## ban hosts for one hour:
    bantime = 3600

    ## override /etc/fail2ban/jail.d/00-firewalld.conf:
    banaction = iptables-multiport

    [sshd]
    enabled = true

    [wordpress-hard]
    enabled = true
    filter = wordpress-hard
    logpath = /var/log/auth.log
    maxretry = 1
    port = http,https

    [wordpress-soft]
    enabled = true
    filter = wordpress-soft
    logpath = /var/log/auth.log
    maxretry = 3
    port = http,https

– exited nano and saved
```

4. `sudo systemctl restart fail2ban` resulted in the following:
   `Job for fail2ban.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See “systemctl status fail2ban.service” and “journalctl -xe” for details.`
5. `systemctl status fail2ban.service` resulted in:

```
fail2ban.service – Fail2Ban Service Loaded: loaded   (/usr/lib/systemd/system/fail2ban.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)  
Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mon 2019-08-05 14:52:20 EDT; 1min 4s ago Docs: man:fail2ban(1)  
Process: 12326 ExecStart=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client -x start (code=exited, status=255)  
Main PID: 9099 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

6. `sudo fail2ban-client status` resulted in:

```
ERROR Failed to access socket path: /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock. Is fail2ban running?
```

7. After seeing the above, I looked for **/var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock**. The file is missing/not there/nonexistent.
8. `journalctl -u fail2ban.service` results in:

```
fail2ban-client[10992]: ERROR Errors in jail ‘wordpress-hard’. Skipping…  
fail2ban-client[10992]: ERROR Found no accessible config files for ‘filter.d/wo  
fail2ban-client[10992]: ERROR No section: ‘Definition’  
fail2ban-client[10992]: ERROR No section: ‘Definition’  
fail2ban-client[10992]: ERROR Unable to read the filter
```

And that’s where I’m at. Did I do something wrong? Did they do something wrong? How to fix? Thanks and My apologies for the length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to copy conf to `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/`

***e.g*** 
sudo cp /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-fail2ban/filters.d/wordpress-hard.conf /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/

*also do not forgot to copy wordpress-soft.conf to filters.d direcotry*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Those files are in the correct location (see #1 above).

Comment: yes but fail2ban doesn't read from `wp-content/plugnins/wp-fail2ban/filters.d/filtter.d` but reads form its own filterd.d folder which is located in `/etc/fail2ban/filterd.d/`

Comment: Ok, see what you're saying. True, there isn't any **-soft.conf** and **-hard.conf** are missing. However, looking at the path you gave above, after **/var/www/html/** there is nothing other than temp files and error pages (eg, 400.shtml, 401.shtml, etc). **wp-content** doesn't exist in that directory.

Comment: I downloaded those conf files from the repository to the filter.d directory. Unfortunately, I continue to receive the same errors.

Comment: > #8 Found no accessible config files. it means that fail2ban is searching  wordpress-hard.conf in `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/`  if you put wordpress-hard.conf file in `/etc/fail2ban/filterd.d/` than fail2ban should start.

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestions. Working with the plugin author I found that I had to create the appropriate log files. Once done, the service started working.